# How can WP_Query use REGEX to search a post_title

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress, search

I have a CPT called "names" with post_titles like

```
Koch
Müller
Schneider
```

Now I want to create a WP_Query where I can search the titles by a custom REGEX. For example I know only the third and last letter of the name: "**ch", "**l**r" or "**h*****r".

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
    's' => '^..[h].....[r]$' 
  ) 
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a regex pattern to match names whose third letter is `h` and final letter is `r`, then use:

```php
$query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        's' => '^..h.*r$' 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: And WP will automatically know that this is supposed to be a regular expression? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#search-parameters only says `s` should be the search keyword in string form. Unless there is any mechanism that “guesses” this is a regex that I don’t know about, I think this needs manipulation of the generated SQL query itself, via one of the hooks.

Comment: @CBroe 
Yes, you are right. It doesn't seem so easy. Can you give me a hint about the hooks you are talking?

I think if we would talk about a custom field you can solve this by `'compare' => 'REGEXP'`

Comment: @mokorana the main hook usually involved is https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/ There are a couple questions here on SO dealing with manipulating the WP search query, probably more on the dedicated WP SE site.